# MySQL Error 1054 - values with hyphens

Tags: mysql, bash

When executing this code in bash:

```
q="$conn 'SELECT name FROM device WHERE uid='0dba9ec2-f2fe-11e5-be09-000c29437b45';'"
r=$(ssh "$ssh_user"@"$ssh_host" $q)
echo "R is.. " $r;
```

I get this output:

"ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column '0dba9ec2' in 'where clause'"

Value of $r is null. I've tried other queries where the WHERE filter value doesn't have hyphens and it works ok, so I'm guessing the hyphens may have something to do with it.

I'd appreciate any guidance on what I could be missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your query. You are using 4 single quotes, cancelling eachother. Instead of outter single quotes, use escaped double quotes `\"`

```
q="$conn \"SELECT name FROM device WHERE uid='0dba9ec2-f2fe-11e5-be09-000c29437b45\";'"
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to add a single quote to close out the uid before the second backslash, but the escaping did it.